# symfony 1.4: error with include_once()

Tags: symfony1

after installing sfDoctrineApplyPlugin-1.1.1, extracting Zend at
lib/vendor/Zend, executing sfApply/apply and submitting the form that
appears i get this errror:

> Warning:
>   include_once(Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php)
>   [function.include-once]: failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory
>   in
>   /home/ptiteshina/workspace/sfprojects/moonrave/plugins/sfDoc
>   trineApplyPlugin/modules/sfApply/lib/BasesfApplyActions.clas
>   s.php on line 350
>
> Warning: include_once()
>   [function.include]: Failed opening
>   'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php' for
>   inclusion
>   (include_path='/home/ptiteshina/workspace/sfprojects/moonrav
>   e/lib/vendor:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
>   in
>   /home/ptiteshina/workspace/sfprojects/moonrave/plugins/sfDoc
>   trineApplyPlugin/modules/sfApply/lib/BasesfApplyActions.clas
>   s.php on line 350
>
> Fatal error: Class
>   'Zend_Loader_Autoloader' not found in
>   /home/ptiteshina/workspace/sfprojects/moonrave/plugins/sfDoc
>   trineApplyPlugin/modules/sfApply/lib/BasesfApplyActions.clas
>   s.php on line 351

If i write
include_once('/opt/lampp/htdocs/rs7/lib/vendor/Zend/library/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');
the error disappears, but you know, i can not use absolute paths.

I tried with some piece of paths instead but it didn't work.

Any idea?

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read [Installing and configuring the Zend Framework](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/17#chapter_17_installing_and_configuring_the_zend_framework) part of a jobeet tutorial? There's a simple way to use Zend autoloader in a ProjectConfiguration.